# Why does the Smith-Waterman algorithm have a complexity of $O(m^2 \times n)$?

Tags: sequence-alignment

I recently read that original the Smith-Waterman algorithm to do a local pairwise alignment of sequences has a complexity of $O(m^2 \times n)$, where $m$ and $n$ would be the lengths of the sequences with $m$ the potentially longer one. What I am wondering is where the additional complexity arises in the algorithm compared to the Needelmann-Wunsch algorithm of global alignment, which has complexity $O(m \times n)$.

Am I correct to assume the $m\times n$ for the Needelmann-Wunsch algorithm comes from building up the scoring matrix - whereas the traceback is negligible in complexity i.e. $O(m\times n + m)$? Hence we arrive at $O(m\times n)$.

Why is there a $m^2$ term for the Smith-Watermann algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

I think your source is wrong. You are correct to assume the brunt of its complexity comes from building the $m *n$ matrix. The main differences are in the calculations per cell and the traceback, but these don't make $m ^2$. Wikipedia also gives an identical $O(m * n)$ as worst case for both algorithms.

edit:
Aparently in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022283682903989?via%3Dihub) the algorithms were improved to go from $m^2n$ to $m*n$

Comment: Yes, the Smith-Waterman algorithm is often called the Smith-Waterman-Gotoh algorithm for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for the great reference. I gave it a read. So under certain gap penalties, the complexity is reduced. I don't yet fully understand why though. Is there a heuristic explanation?